# How to forget Time Machine password from keychain

Tags: time-machine, keychain

When attaching a Time Machine, I am asked if I want to remember the password in the keychain. If I do that, how can I "forget" the password?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Make sure you really understand how keychain works before deciding to tamper with it.  if you forget the password, the only solution is erasing the disk.

Answer (score 0):

[Launch Keychain Access, unlock your keychain, and then delete the entry you don't need](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/delete-a-keychain-kyca2423/mac). This will cause the keychain to **forget** that entry.

Comment: How would I be able to identify the entry I am looking for?

Comment: You would search for the name of the volume

Comment: You would also check the password before you delete the item, and make sure that it is either a password that you remember, or a time machine backup that you absolutely don't need anymore. If you remove the password from the keychain and cannot remember it, that time machine backup is gone.